# Is there a way to submit my form to both a url and send data to an email?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Hey guys I have a simple form which needs to post to a url however i would also like the data to be sent to an email.  Is this possible?

Here is my current code:

```
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<title>Test Form - Overture</title>
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>
<script src="https://malsup.github.io/jquery.form.js"></script> 
 
<script> 

// Form to submit via ajax.

$("form").ajaxForm({
"clearForm": false,
"resetForm": true,
"beforeSubmit": function() {
},
"success": function(json) {
if (json.success == true)
{
// Form has submitted successfully.
alert("Thank you for getting in touch.");
window.location.href = "https://www.activetalentagency.com/booking-request-confirmation";

} else {
for (name in json.errors) {
$("form").find("[name$='" + json.errors[name] + "']").css("border-color", "red");
};
};
},
"error": function() {}
});
</script> 

</head>

<body>

<form method="post" action="https://overturehq.com/formapi/webform/submit.json">

<h2>Test Form</h2>
 <label>Name:</label>
<input type="text" name="personName" required>
<label>Email Address:</label>
<input type="text" name="personEmailWork" required>
<label>Phone Number:</label>
<input type="text" name="personPhoneWork" required>
<label>What would you like to discuss with us?</label>
<textarea name="personNote"></textarea>

<input type="submit" value="Send Enquiry">
<input type="hidden" name="key" value="MTI4NzQxNTE1NzI=">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Im hoping there might be a way even if its collecting the data somehow and then submitting it to both places email and url.

Comment: 1. Your code will not work well since the script is executing before the form exists
2. It is not recommended to send mail on the client. The user might not have a mail client set up. 3. where is the email in your script? Why not submit the form to the server, send the email and redirect to the URL from the server. Your jQuery is ancient and malsups form ajax is unnecessary

Comment: @mplungjan thanks for the reply! As you can tell I don’t deal much with php/html the form was an amended one which is why the jquery is probably ancient and has malsup. So what is the preference send the data to a separate php to handle both.

Comment: Submit the form. send the email from the php and use header to redirect to the other page

Comment: The header on the form page to send to the url, and the php to send the email data.

Comment: No. Send the form data to the server (https://overturehq.com/formapi/webform/submit.json or whatever). The server sends the email and ends with `header("location:https://www.activetalentagency.com/booking-request-confirmation");` if php

Comment: @mplungjan ah ok! Problem is I don’t have access to that server. As that is another company which runs the software we use. Is there another way around this?

Comment: You have access to neither https://overturehq.com/formapi/webform/submit.json  nor https://www.activetalentagency.com/booking-request-confirmation? you do not actually need access to the request confirmation since that is just where the user ends

Comment: Sorry I do have access to https://www.activetalentagency.com/booking-request-confirmation server

Comment: What does `https://overturehq.com/formapi/webform/submit.json` do for you then?

Comment: You COULD call `https://overturehq.com/formapi/webform/submit.json` from `https://www.activetalentagency.com/booking-request-confirmation` before sending email and return a success message

Comment: It pulls the form data and transfers it into a database which is a 3rd party software.

Comment: @mplungjan that sounds like a better option to call https://overturehq.com/formapi/webform/submit.json from activetalentagency.com this way could I send also an email whilst ssending the data.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can asynchronously post the data to a URL and in the same function use a module like nodemailer to asynchronously generate and send an email with the same data. You can really do anything you want to do.

Comment: That’s great thanks @Sean Lawton would it just be as simple as changing part of my current form action code?

Comment: I would recommend calling a function on the form submission that would wrap and execute both the Ajax call and the email function at the same time asynchronously. In jQuery you can add a .on('submit') event handler that can execute what ever you want when the form is submitted. Here's a link: https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/faq/how-to-ajax-submit-a-form-in-jquery.php

Comment: I see so create a separate php file to handle the email submission part. Would the php file handle both the url and email in that case?

Comment: It can, yes. You can post that data to a PHP file and do all the abstraction that way. Saving data in the database and emailing the data as well.

Comment: Perfect! I just need to find how to program the php file to do both! If you know of anything @Sean Lawton that would be great!

Comment: I'm not sure what your stack looks like but here's a link demonstrating some ways to send emails with PHP. https://www.guru99.com/php-mail.html

Comment: Would the jquery handle the url I need it send to on the form page then and just the php sending the mail

Comment: You can do it that way. I'd recommend looking into REST APIs and how they work.

Comment: Ok I’ll look into that. Thanks again Sean